# How is audio represented with numbers in computers?

Tags: audio

I like thinking about how everything can be and is represented by numbers. For example, plaintext is represented by a code like ASCII, and images are represented by RGB values. These are the simplest ways to represent text and images.

What is the simplest way that audio can be represented with numbers? I want to learn how to write programs that work with audio and thought this would be a good way to start. I can't seem to find any good explanations on the internet, though.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Physically, as you probably know, audio is a vibration. Typically, we're
talking about vibrations of air between approximitely 20Hz and 20,000Hz.
That means the air is moving back and forth 20 to 20,000 times per
second.

If you measure that vibration and convert it to an electrical signal
(say, using a microphone), you'll get an electrical signal with the
voltage varying in the same waveform as the sound. In our pure-tone
hypothetical, that waveform will match that of the sine function.

Now, we have an analogue signal, the voltage. Still not digital. But, we
know this voltage varies between (for example) -1V and +1V. We can, of
course, attach a volt meter to the wires and read the voltage.

Arbitrarily, we'll change the scale on our volt meter. We'll multiple
the volts by 32767. It now calls -1V *-32767* and +1V *32767*. Oh, and
it'll round to the nearest integer.

Now, we hook our volt meter to a computer, and instruct the computer to
read the meter 44,100 times per second. Add a second volt meter (for the
other stereo channel), and we now have the data that goes on an audio
CD.

This format is called *stereo 44,100 Hz, 16-bit linear PCM*. And it really is
just a bunch of voltage measurements.

Comment: Technically speaking it's a bunch of amplitude measurements. It just happens to be that most ADCs use voltage to represent the amplitude.

Comment: @SteveKuo technically speaking, that is correct, but it seems like adding that in any meaningful way would complicate the issue greatly. And since this isn't an electrical engineering site...

Comment: @SteveKuo: The term "amplitude" as applied to sound can itself mean multiple things--pressure, velocity, acceleration, or displacement.  At a given frequency in a given environment, all those values will be proportional, but frequency, temperature, enclosure shape, etc. can affect them all differently.  For example, within a cone-shaped megaphone, a given amount of pressure variation will cause more displacement near the small end than near the large one.

Comment: @derobert When i'm reading frames of a mono WAV file using python wave module..it returns ['\xcf\xd0','\x9c\xd3','\x96\xd6','\xb9\xd9'] etc frame data..I want to know whether these frame values can be compared to  ["+207 & -208", "+156 & -211", "+150 & -214", "+185 & -217"] ???

Comment: @Raza The exact format it returns depends on the API and also possibly the file. But that looks like 16 bits per sample. CFD0 is one number, 9CD3 is another, etc. You probably want to ask your own question with details (search first, of course, to check it hasn't already been asked.)

Comment: @derobert actually I'm trying this 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9910779

the frame length is 2 bytes for single channel audio file. Want to make sure if we can treat the 1st byte of frame as +ve and 2nd byte of the frame as -ve amplitude of the signal as per explanation  ??

Comment: @Raza there is one number per channel, per frame. Mono would be one channel only. Those two bytes are one number, not two; between -32768 and 32767. But I don't know that API, or Python for that matter...

Comment: @derobert Thanks for your quick response...no problem..I've posted a new question,Lets see..

Answer (score 20):

**Minimal C audio generation example**

The example below generates a pure 1000k Hz sinus in raw format. At the common 44.1kHz sampling rate, it will last about 4 seconds.

main.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f;
    const double PI2 = 2 * acos(-1.0);
    const double SAMPLE_FREQ = 44100;
    const unsigned int NSAMPLES = 4 * SAMPLE_FREQ;
    uint16_t ampl;
    uint8_t bytes[2];
    unsigned int t;

    f = fopen("out.raw", "wb");
    for (t = 0; t < NSAMPLES; ++t) {
        ampl = UINT16_MAX * 0.5 * (1.0 + sin(PI2 * t * 1000.0 / SAMPLE_FREQ));
        bytes[0] = ampl >> 8;
        bytes[1] = ampl & 0xFF;
        fwrite(bytes, 2, sizeof(uint8_t), f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/d046111efbd6353bd5d8df16733472baab2ffc52/c/interactive/audio_gen.c).

Generate `out.raw`:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o main main.c -lm
./main
```

Play `out.raw` directly:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffplay -autoexit -f u16be -ar 44100 -ac 1 out.raw
```

or convert to a more common audio format and then play with a more common audio player:

```
ffmpeg -f u16be -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i out.raw out.flac
vlc out.flac
```

Generated FLAC file: https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/master/canon.flac

Parameters explained at: https://superuser.com/questions/76665/how-to-play-a-pcm-file-on-an-unix-system/1063230#1063230

Related: [What ffmpeg command to use to convert a list of unsigned integers into an audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286149/what-ffmpeg-command-to-use-to-convert-a-list-of-unsigned-integers-into-an-audio)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Canon in D in C**

Here is a more interesting synthesis example.

Outcome: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JISozfHATms

main.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint16_t point_type_t;

double PI2;

void write_ampl(FILE *f, point_type_t ampl) {
    uint8_t bytes[2];
    bytes[0] = ampl >> 8;
    bytes[1] = ampl & 0xFF;
    fwrite(bytes, 2, sizeof(uint8_t), f);
}

/* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies */
double piano_freq(unsigned int i) {
    return 440.0 * pow(2, (i - 49.0) / 12.0);
}

/* Chord formed by the nth note of the piano. */
point_type_t piano_sum(unsigned int max_ampl, unsigned int time,
        double sample_freq, unsigned int nargs, unsigned int *notes) {
    unsigned int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < nargs; ++i)
        sum += sin(PI2 * time * piano_freq(notes[i]) / sample_freq);
    return max_ampl * 0.5 * (nargs + sum) / nargs;
}

enum notes {
    A0 = 1, AS0, B0,
    C1, C1S, D1, D1S, E1, F1, F1S, G1, G1S, A1, A1S, B1,
    C2, C2S, D2, D2S, E2, F2, F2S, G2, G2S, A2, A2S, B2,
    C3, C3S, D3, D3S, E3, F3, F3S, G3, G3S, A3, A3S, B3,
    C4, C4S, D4, D4S, E4, F4, F4S, G4, G4S, A4, A4S, B4,
    C5, C5S, D5, D5S, E5, F5, F5S, G5, G5S, A5, A5S, B5,
    C6, C6S, D6, D6S, E6, F6, F6S, G6, G6S, A6, A6S, B6,
    C7, C7S, D7, D7S, E7, F7, F7S, G7, G7S, A7, A7S, B7,
    C8,
};

int main(void) {
    FILE *f;
    PI2 = 2 * acos(-1.0);
    const double SAMPLE_FREQ = 44100;
    point_type_t ampl;
    point_type_t max_ampl = UINT16_MAX;
    unsigned int t, i;
    unsigned int samples_per_unit = SAMPLE_FREQ * 0.375;
    unsigned int *ip[] = {
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, C3, E4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, G3, D4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, A3, C4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, E3, B3},

        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, F3, A3},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, C3, G3},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, F3, A3},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, G3, B3},

        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, C3, G4, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, G3, B4, D5},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 2, A3,     C5},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, E3, G4, B4},

        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, F3, C4, A4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, C3, G4, G4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, F3, F4, A4},
        (unsigned int[]){4, 3, G3, D4, B4},

        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, C4, E4, C5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, C4, E4, C5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, G3, D4, D5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, G3, D4, B4},

        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, A3, C4, C5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, A3, C4, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 2, E3,     G5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 2, E3,     G4},

        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, F3, A3, A4},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, F3, A3, F4},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, C3,     E4},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, C3,     G4},

        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, F3, A3, F4},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, F3, A3, C5},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, G3, B3, B4},
        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, G3, B3, G4},

        (unsigned int[]){2, 3, C4, E4, C5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, C4, E4, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, C4, E4, G5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 2, G3,     G5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 2, G3,     A5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 2, G3,     G5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 2, G3,     F5},

        (unsigned int[]){3, 3, A3, C4, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, A3, C4, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, E3, G3, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, E3, G3, F5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, E3, G3, E5},
        (unsigned int[]){1, 3, E3, G3, D5},
    };
    f = fopen("canon.raw", "wb");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ip) / sizeof(int*); ++i) {
        unsigned int *cur = ip[i];
        unsigned int total = samples_per_unit * cur[0];
        for (t = 0; t < total; ++t) {
            ampl = piano_sum(max_ampl, t, SAMPLE_FREQ, cur[1], &cur[2]);
            write_ampl(f, ampl);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/d046111efbd6353bd5d8df16733472baab2ffc52/c/interactive/audio_gen.c#L214).

For YouTube, I prepared it as:

```
wget -O canon.png https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/The_C_Programming_Language_logo.svg/564px-The_C_Programming_Language_logo.svg.png
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i canon.png -i canon.flac -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec vp9 canon.mkv
```

as explained at: https://superuser.com/questions/700419/how-to-convert-mp3-to-youtube-allowed-video-format/1472572#1472572

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Physics**

Audio is encoded as a single number for every moment in time. Compare that to a video, which needs WIDTH * HEIGHT numbers per moment in time.

This number is then converted to the linear displacement of the [diaphragm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_%28acoustics%29) of your speaker:

```
|   /
|  /
|-/
| | A   I   R
|-\
|  \
|   \
<-> displacement

|     /
|    /
|---/
|   | A I   R
|---\
|    \
|     \
<---> displacement

|       /
|      /
|-----/
|     | A I R
|-----\
|      \
|       \
<-----> displacement
```

The displacement pushes air backwards and forwards, creating pressure differences, which travel through air as [P-waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-wave).

Only displacement matters: a constant signal, even if maximal, produces no sound: the diaphragm just stays at a fixed position.

The [sampling frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29) determines how fast the displacements should be done.

[44,1kHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/44,100_Hz) is a common sampling frequency because humans can hear up to 20kHz and because of the [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

The sampling frequency is analogous to the FPS for video, although it has a much higher value compared to the 25 (cinema) - 144 (hardcore gaming monitors) range we commonly see for video.

**Formats**

Uncompressed:

- `.raw` is an underspecified format that contains just the amplitude bytes, and no metadata.

  We have to pass a few meta-data parameters on the command line like the sampling frequency because the format does not contain that data.
- `.wav` is another popular uncompressed format which contain all needed metadata: [WAV File Synthesis From Scratch - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844122/wav-file-synthesis-from-scratch-c)
- MIDI (`.mid`): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI

  This format represents keystrokes of an instrument. File sizes can be very small as a result, but it can't necessarily represent "arbitrary sounds", more like notes. It is what a basic digital keyboard will output to a computer. You then need a synthesizer software to transform those notes into actual sound amplitudes. Also it is harder to make it portable, and the receiver would need the exact same synthesis software/database.

  Conversion to MP3: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/automatically-turn-midi-files-into-wav-or-mp3/76955#76955

In practice, most people deal exclusively with compressed formats, which make files  streaming much smaller. Some of those formats take into account characteristics of the human ear to further compress the audio in a lossy way that people won't notice. The most popular royalty free formats as of 2019 appear to be:

- lossless: [FLAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC)
- lossy: [Vorbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis)

**Biology**

Humans perceive sound mostly by their frequency decomposition (AKA [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)).

I think this is because the inner ear has parts which resonate to different frequencies (TODO confirm).

Therefore, when synthesizing music, we think more in terms of adding up frequencies instead of points in time. This is illustrated [in this example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/f734a2e76fbcfc67f707ae06be7a2a2ef5db47d1/c/interactive/audio_gen.c#L123).

This leads to thinking in terms of a 1D vector between 20Hz and 20kHz for each point in time.

The mathematical Fourier transform loses the notion of time, so what we do when synthesizing is to take groups of points, and sum up frequencies for that group, and take the Fourier transform there.

Luckily, the Fourier transform is linear, so we can just add up and normalize displacements directly.

The size of each group of points leads to a time - frequency precision tradeoff, mediated by the same mathematics as [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).

[Wavelets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279980/difference-between-fourier-transform-and-wavelets) may be a more precise mathematical description of this intermediary time - frequency description.

**Quick ways to generate common tones out of the box**

The amazing FFmpeg library covers several of them: [Linux sine wave audio generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109038/linux-sinus-audio-generator/57610684#57610684)

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" out.wav
```

**LMMS**

This is so incredibly easy to use, it should be your first try if you just want to generate some MIDI tracks with lots of synthesis options out of the box.

Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/709673/save-as-midi-when-playing-from-vmpk-qsynth/1298231#1298231

**MuseScore**

https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore

The best FOSS [scorewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorewriter) GUI I've seen so far. You can really compose for an orchestra with this.

**Csound**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csound

https://github.com/csound/csound

Program that reads a custom XML format that allows you to create some very funky arbitrary synthesized sounds and tunes.

```
sudo apt install csound
```

Here's a really cool and advanced demo: https://github.com/csound/csound/blob/b319c336d31d942af2d279b636339df83dc9f9f9/examples/xanadu.csd rendered at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fXhVMDCfaA

The program feels both archaic and hyperadvanced at the same time.

**abcmidi**

Nice project that converts MIDI to the [ABC notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_notation) and vice versa, allowing you to edit a MIDI file in your text editor: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/39457/how-to-open-midi-file-in-text-editor/50058#50058

**Python pyo**

https://github.com/belangeo/pyo

Python sound library.

Got it to work after a bit of frustration: [Pyo server.boot() fails with pyolib._core.PyoServerStateException on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445375/pyo-server-boot-fails-with-pyolib-core-pyoserverstateexception-on-ubuntu-14-0/64960589#64960589)

**MusicXML**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicXML

An attempt to standardize music sheet representation.

I can't find easily how to convert it to an audio format from the command line however... [Convert musicxml to wav?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775336/convert-musicxml-to-wav/64974602#64974602)

**Other high level out-of-box open source synthesizers for Linux**

If you are going down this road, you might as well have a look at the big boys to learn about common synthesis techniques:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXCwH9n3M-c Zyn-Fusion + Ardour synthesis music composition tutorial "from scratch" by unfa, big kudos to him
- how to get ZynAddSubFX running on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340204/zynaddsubfx-fails-to-initialize-with-error-message-default-i-o-did-not-initiali/1238546#1238546
- http://linuxsynths.com/ quick review of ALL of them with generated audio samples

Comment: Hi, I tried to run the c program an i am getting values like this
f408 fa00 fe00 ff08 fe00 fa00 f408 ec00
can they be converted to an Int value?

Comment: @free_style the file is raw binary, so you must be viewing it with some viewer? Have a google for "c convert binary to decimal".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the links.

Answer (score 9):

Audio can represented by digital samples.  Essentially, a sampler (also called an Analog to digital converter) grabs a value of an audio signal every 1/fs, where fs is the sampling frequency.  The ADC, then quantizes the signal, which is a rounding operation.  So if your signal ranges from 0 to 3 Volts (Full Scale Range) then a sample will be rounded to, for example a 16-bit number.  In this example, a 16-bit number is recorded once every 1/fs/

So for example, most WAV/MP3s are sampled an audio signal at 44 kHz.  I don't know how detail you want, but there's this thing called the "Nyquist Sampling Rate" the says that the sampling frequency must be at least twice the desired frequency.  So on your WAV/MP3 file you are at best going to be able to hear up tp 22 kHz frequencies.

There is a lot of detail you can go into in this area.  The simplest form would certainly be the WAV format.  It is uncompressed audio.  Formats like mp3 and ogg are have to be decompressed before you can work with them.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to represent sound as numbers is PCM (Pulse Code Modulation). This means that the amplitude of the sound is recorded at a set frequency (each amplitude value is called a sample). CD quality sound for example is 16 bit samples (in stereo) at the frequency 44100 Hz.

A sample can be represented as an integer number (usually 8, 12, 16, 24 or 32 bits) or a floating point number (16 bit float or 32 bit double). The number can either be signed or unsigned.

For 16 bit signed samples the value 0 would be in the middle, and -32768 and 32767 would be the maximum amplitues. For 16 bit unsigned samples the value 32768 would be in the middle, and 0 and 65535 would be the maximum amplitudes.

For floating point samples the usual format is that 0 is in the middle, and -1.0 and 1.0 are the maximum amplitudes.

The PCM data can then be compressed, for example using MP3.

Comment: It might be worth noting that when representing sound as integers, the minimum and maximum values are absolutes; if sound is processed through multiple steps and any step would exceed that amplitude, clipping will result [generally very harsh sounding].  When passing floating-point audio through multiple processing steps, clipping will likely result if the final audio has values outside the +/- 1.0 range, but intermediate stages may go outside that range without causing clipping.

Answer (score 4):

I think samples of the waveform at a specific sample frequency would be the most basic representation.

Comment: Correct--the technical term for this is "linear pulse-code modulation."

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever looked at a waveform close up? The Y-axis is simply represented as an integer, typically in 16 bits.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good way to start playing with audio would be with [Processing](http://processing.org/) and [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/).
This program will draw the frequency spectrum of sound from your microphone!

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;

AudioInput in;
FFT fft;

void setup()
{
  size(1024, 600);
  noSmooth();
  Minim.start(this);
  in = Minim.getLineIn();
  fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(), in.sampleRate());
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  fft.forward(in.mix);
  stroke(255);
  for(int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++)
    line(i*2+1, height, i*2+1, height - fft.getBand(i)*10);
}

void stop()
{
  in.close();
  Minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up things like analog-digital conversion. That should get you started. These devices can convert a audio signal (sine waves) into digital representations. So, a 16-bit ADC would be able to represent a sine from between -32768 to 32768. This is in fixed-point. It is also possible to do it in floating-point (though not recommended for performance reasons but may be needed for range reasons). The opposite (digital-analog conversion) happens when we convert numbers to sine waves. This is handled by something called a DAC.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps involved in converting actual analogous audio into a digital form.

1. Sampling
2. Quantization

**Sampling**

The rate at which a continuous waveform (in this case, audio) is sampled, is called the sampling rate. The frequency range perceived by humans is 20 - 20,000 Hz. However, CDs use the Nyquist sampling theorem, which means sampling rate of 44,100 Hz, covers frequencies in the range 0 - 22,050Hz.

**Quantization**

The discrete set of values received from the 'Sampling' phase now need to be converted into a finite number of values. An 8-bit quantization provides 256 possible values, while a 16 bit quantization provides upto 65,536 values.

Answer (score 0):

The answers all relate to sampling frequency, but don't address the question.  A particular snapshot of a sound would, I imagine, include individual amplitudes for a lot of different frequencies (say you hit both an A and a C simultaneously on a keyboard, with the A being louder).  How does that get recorded in a 16 bit number?  If all you are doing is measuring amplitude (how loud the sound is), how do you get the different notes?

Ah!  I think I get it from this comment:  "This number is then converted to the linear displacement of the diaphragm of your speaker." The notes appear by how fast the diaphragm is vibrating.  That's why you need the 44,000 different values per second.  A note is somewhere on the order of 1000 hertz, so a pure note would make the diaphragm move in and out about 1000 times per second.  A recording of a whole orchestrate has many different notes all over the place, and that miraculously can be converted into a single time history of diaphragm motion.  44,000 times per second the diaphragm is instructed to move in or out a little bit, and that simple (long) list of numbers can represent Beyonce to Beethoven!