# Linux sine wave audio generator

Tags: linux, audio

I want to use my laptop as sinus generator under linux. But I have not found a program that can generate sound. Can someone tell me the right program or script for it. Thank you.

PS: I don't want use wine for it.
PS2: I found this: "aoss siggen" and "speaker_test". But first ncurses based and second can not generate a continuous signal. May be you know more?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to generate sound files under linux, I recommend [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Mmm, cool. Command sample: "play -n synth sin 1000 gain 1"

Comment: `gain 1` will make it clip. Don't add any gain, sin is already rail-to-rail.

Answer (score 12):

Pulseaudio has a [module for generating sine waves](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-sine):

```
$ pactl load-module module-sine frequency=1000
```

And to make it stop:

```
$ pactl unload-module module-sine
```

Comment: +1 That's a fun thing...

Comment: I was going to add the most important part of the page in the answer because the link might die in the future, but it's ironically already dead. This is why we have this guideline for answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Use `pactl load-module module-sine frequency=440; read; pactl unload-module module-sine` to make it stop after you press a key.

Answer (score 12):

**ffmpeg**

ffmpeg can do it, as usual.

Create a 2 second mono 1000 Hz sinusoidal `out.wav` sound file:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000:d=2" out.wav
```

Stereo instead with `-ac 2`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000:d=2" -ac 2 out.wav
```

The file will be 2x as large, and `ffprobe` will say it has `2 channels` instead of `1 channel`.

Generate 2 seconds of 500 Hz on left and 1000 Hz on right, related question: [How to generate stereo sine wave using FFMPEG with different frequencies for each channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551013/how-to-generate-stereo-sine-wave-using-ffmpeg)

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex '
sine=f=500[0];
sine=f=1000[1];
[0][1]amerge,atrim=end=2
' out.wav
```

Play the 1000 Hz for 2 seconds without creating a file:

```
ffplay -autoexit -nodisp -f lavfi -i 'sine=f=1000:d=2'
```

Play 1000 Hz forever until you go mad:

```
ffplay -nodisp -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000"
```

Produce a 2 second mixture/overlay of 500 Hz and 1000 Hz on both channels, related question: [How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-downmix-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=500[0];
sine=f=1000[1];
[0][1]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2
'
```

Produce 2 seconds of 500 Hz followed by 2 seconds of 1000 Hz:

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=500:d=2[0];
sine=f=1000:d=2[1];
[0][1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1
'
```

2 seconds of 250 Hz + 500 Hz followed by two seconds of 1000 Hz + 2000 Hz:

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=250[0];
sine=f=500[1];
sine=f=1000[2];
sine=f=2000[3];
[0][1]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2[01];
[2][3]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2[23];
[01][23]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out];
'
```

Frequency sweep from 0 to 20 kHZ over 10 seconds, main question: https://superuser.com/questions/1156429/how-to-generate-a-time-dependent-frequency-wave/1156468#1156468

```
ffplay -autoexit -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc='sin(2000*t*2*PI*t)':d=10"
```

Documentation:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine
- https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi

The other section sunder [Audio sources](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Audio-Sources) document other useful sound generation algorithms in addition to `sine`, e.g.:

- [`anoisesrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anoisesrc): several noises
- [`aevalsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc) takes arbitrary mathematical expressions!

Bibliography:

- https://superuser.com/questions/724391/how-to-generate-a-sine-wave-with-ffmpeg
- [How to run ffplay as a window-less process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831214/how-to-run-ffplay-as-a-window-less-process/53295994#53295994)

Tested on ffmpeg 6.0, Ubuntu 23.10.

**Minimal C audio generation example without extra libraries**

Just for fun: [How is audio represented with numbers in computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732699/how-is-audio-represented-with-numbers-in-computers/36510894#36510894)

Comment: You could use `-v warning` to disable logging to stderr, if there are no warnings or some more serious problems.

Comment: ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration='0.1'" -autoexit -nodisp # if you want duration less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Today Linux uses the [Alsa](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) infrastructure for sound. Check out [Alsa documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/) and tutorials (for instance [this one](http://www.equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html)).

Comment: And in particular see the sine wave generator example in the ALSA docs: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking around on google I found this software, not sure if it is what you are looking for.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/Multisine.shtml

You could run it under wine.

Oh... before the additional note in the original post, sorry.

Edit: Woohoo, found one!

http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/jj/linux/siggen.html

Apparently the software Audacity can do it also.

Referencing http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=308065