# How to generate stereo sine wave using FFMPEG with different frequencies for each channel?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to generate a stereo sine wave using FFMPEG (batch file), but have a different frequency for left and right. So far I have this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=60" -ac 2 "binaural.wav"
```

But it creates the same frequency for both left and right.
Is this possible?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82112/stereo-tone-generator-for-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two sine filters and merge them.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=60" -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=600:duration=60" -filter_complex amerge  "binaural.wav"
```

Comment: How to do this with `ffplay` instead? I tried: `ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=60" -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=600:duration=60" -filter_complex amerge` but it failed with: `Argument 'sine=frequency=600:duration=60' provided as input filename, but 'sine=frequency=1000:duration=60' was already specified.`.

Comment: `ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=60[a];sine=frequency=600:duration=60[b];[a][b]amerge"`

Answer (score 0):

A very slightly improved version of Gyan's answer based on his teachings. It generates 2 seconds of 500 Hz on left and 1000 Hz on right, but using `atrim` so we don't have to repeat the duration `2` separately for both inputs:

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex '
sine=frequency=500[a];
sine=frequency=1000[b];
[a][b]amerge,atrim=end=2
' out.wav
```

For playing the sound directly without saving to a file you can:

```
ffplay -autoexit -nodisp -f lavfi -i '
sine=frequency=500[a];
sine=frequency=1000[b];
[a][b]amerge,atrim=end=2
'
```

This produces:

- two separate infinite sines
- merges them on separate channels with `amerge` two infinite merged sines
- then cuts that down to two seconds

The `,` means piping and creates an implicitly named graph edge so we've created a graph like:

```
                              +--------+
[sine=frequency=500]--->[a]-->|        |
                              | amerge |-->[atrim]-->[output]
[sine=frequency=1000]-->[b]-->|        |
                              +--------+
```

Tested on ffmpeg 6.0, Ubuntu 23.10.