# Getting positive and negative component of a signal from raw wav audio

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I was reading this StackOverflow post:

[How is audio represented with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732699/how-is-audio-represented-with-numbers?answertab=votes#tab-top)

According to the answer the digital signal will have one +ve component and one negative component. So i'm trying to relate this with a very basic wav audio file.

I'm reading all frames of one WAV audio file using python. I using below code:

```
import wave
import sys
ip = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
print ip.getparams()
for i in range(ip.getnframes()):
    iframe = ip.readframes(1)
    print iframe.encode('hex') , ' >>> ',int(iframe.encode('hex'), 16)
ip.close()

'''
Output :
C:\>python readframe.py test.wav
(1, 2, 44100, 176400, 'NONE', 'not compressed')
0000  >>>  0
0204  >>>  516
0008  >>>  8
f70b  >>>  63243
e10f  >>>  57615
bb13  >>>  47891
8217  >>>  33303
311b  >>>  12571
c41e  >>>  50206
3922  >>>  14626
8b25  >>>  35621
b728  >>>  46888
bb2b  >>>  47915
922e  >>>  37422
3b31  >>>  15153
b233  >>>  45619
f535  >>>  62773

'''
```

My question is how can I get the positive and negative component of the wav audio from each frame data ..??

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to read *.wav file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/how-to-read-wav-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Values larger than 32767 need to be subtracted from 2^16 to get their negative value converted from a 16-bit 2-complement signed representation.

Comment: Thanks fro your response..Whats the significance of 2^16 = 65536 ??